# Correct Ruby on Rails Model Associations for "Liking" Items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I'm writing my first Rails app and I'm stuck at the database level.  I have 2 models: `User` and `Mission`.  They are connected very *unshockingly* like so:

```
User has_many :missions, dependent: :destroy
Mission belongs_to :user
```

I would like other users to be able to interact with missions by either: **liking them** and/or **marking them as completed**

This is all very vanilla stuff here, but I'm struggling with adding this additional layer of interaction into the models.

I started by creating a table `Bond` with attributes `user_id` `mission_id` `liked`:boolean `completed`:boolean

I added the a `has_many :through` relationship like so:

```
User has_many :bonds, dependent: :destroy
User has_many :missions, through: bonds

Mission has_many :bonds
Mission has_many :users, through: :bonds

Bond belongs_to :user
Bond belongs_to :mission
```

I'm having trouble declaring a single user as the *author* of a mission as I now have a many-to-many relationship between these models.

**Is there any way to declare that a `mission` has just one "author" from the `users` table?**